# How to mock third party React Native NativeModules?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-native, mocha.js

A component is importing a library that includes a native module. Here is a contrived example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Answers } from 'react-native-fabric';

export default function MyTouchComponent({ params }) {
  return <View onPress={() => { Answers.logContentView() }} />
}
```

And here is the relevant part of `Answers` from `react-native-fabric`:

```js
var { NativeModules, Platform } = require('react-native');
var SMXAnswers = NativeModules.SMXAnswers;
```

When importing this component in a mocha test, this fails on account that `SMXAnswers` is `undefined`:

How do you mock `SMXAnswers` or `react-native-fabric` so that it doesn't break and allows you to test your components?

p.s.: you can see the [full setup](https://github.com/digisquare/mobile/blob/701cb8704e874864fbc13afd0325f008a5baad9e/test/setup.js) and the [component](https://github.com/digisquare/mobile/blob/701cb8704e874864fbc13afd0325f008a5baad9e/js/scenes/organizations/OrganizationsRow.js) I'm trying to test on GitHub.

Comment: At last I found exactly the same question I have. Unfortunately, there are no answers (as of now). Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @Michael I answered my question below yesterday ; did you see it?

Comment: Thank you very much for answering your question. I actually created a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633977/react-native-testing-mocking-redux-async-action-creators. For now I have moved my native dependencies to a separate module so it won't interfere with my tests. But I'll definitely use your Mockery-setup anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mockery` to mock any native modules like so:

```js
import mockery from 'mockery';

mockery.enable();
mockery.warnOnUnregistered(false);
mockery.registerMock('react-native-fabric', {
  Crashlytics: {
    crash: () => {},
  },
});
```

Here is a complete [setup example](https://github.com/digisquare/mobile/blob/f489ec8b28a91f84ebee38eda6278dc56c04fef4/test/setup.js):

```js
import 'core-js/fn/object/values';
import 'react-native-mock/mock';

import mockery from 'mockery';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import register from 'babel-core/register';

mockery.enable();
mockery.warnOnUnregistered(false);
mockery.registerMock('react-native-fabric', {
  Crashlytics: {
    crash: () => {},
  },
});

const modulesToCompile = [
  'react-native',
].map((moduleName) => new RegExp(`/node_modules/${moduleName}`));

const rcPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '.babelrc');
const source = fs.readFileSync(rcPath).toString();
const config = JSON.parse(source);

config.ignore = function(filename) {
  if (!(/\/node_modules\//).test(filename)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    const matches = modulesToCompile.filter((regex) => regex.test(filename));
    const shouldIgnore = matches.length === 0;
    return shouldIgnore;
  }
}

register(config);
```