# React Native - Error: Cannot find module 'StyleSheet'

Tags: react-native, mocha.js

My app itself is running fine. When I try to implement a mocha unit test which imports my `App.js` I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'StyleSheet'
```

What could the cause for this be? Below how I import the StyleSheet in my `App.js`

```
import {
  StyleSheet, Text, View,
} from 'react-native';
```

Use of `StyleSheet` in `App.js`

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Complete code of `test.js`

```
const assert = require('assert');
import { sum } from '../../App';
describe('Sum', function() {
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function() {
      function getRandomInt(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
      }
      const firstInput = getRandomInt(10);
      const secondInput = getRandomInt(10);
      assert.equal(firstInput + secondInput, sum(firstInput, secondInput));
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you also add the code how you use the `StyleSheet` ?

Comment: Added in my original message!

Comment: With your update, my answer is wrong, I will delete it

Answer (score 0):

Mocha is not recommended for testing React Native. It works much better with Jest and Enzyme. However, if you really want to, there are ways to circunvent this. Take a peak [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-360/issues/67), [here](https://gist.github.com/jmreidy/4145809229195441d4d4) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292512/how-to-mock-third-party-react-native-nativemodules)